# How to generate pdf in MVC webapi which contain graph

Tags: model-view-controller, pdf-generation

I want to generate pdf for report . Report contain bar chart and pie chart .
how can we generate all in web api using MVC 5

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.First, you have to generate pdf which contains bar chart or pie chart and store into your project folder(give your project folder name similar to `pdf`).After you can call your web API HttpGet method in which set path of your pdf which contains charts.